# Method failing after 3310 successes

Tags: c#, icons, pinvoke, handle

I have inherited the following extension method which creates an ImageSource object based on a file path

```
public static class ImageSourceExtensions
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SHFILEINFO
    {
        public IntPtr hIcon;
        public int iIcon;
        public uint dwAttributes;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string szDisplayName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 80)]
        public string szTypeName;
    };

    public const uint SHGFI_ICON = 0x100;
    public const uint SHGFI_LARGEICON = 0x0;

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SHGetFileInfo(string pszPath, uint dwFileAttributes, ref SHFILEINFO psfi, uint cbSizeFileInfo, uint uFlags);

    public static ImageSource GetIconFromFolder(this string filePath)
    {
        SHFILEINFO shinfo = new SHFILEINFO();
        SHGetFileInfo(filePath, 0, ref shinfo, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(shinfo),
                SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON);

        using (Icon i = Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon))
        {
            //Convert icon to a Bitmap source
            ImageSource img = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
                                    i.Handle,
                                    new Int32Rect(0, 0, i.Width, i.Height),
                                    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            return img;
        }
    }
}
```

This extension method works perfectly for both folders and files 3310 times. On the 3311th method call, the following exception is thrown:

> 'Win32 handle that was passed to Icon is not valid or is the wrong
>   type'

This error is thrown when using the **shinfo.hIcon** property.

The error was initially thrown in my main application and was on a different file each time. I have since extracted this class into a new project and can get the same error to be thrown (after the same number of times) by doing this on a button click:

```
String path = @"C:\Generic Folder\Generic Document.pdf";

        for (int i = 0; i <4000; i++)
        {
            ImageSource img = path.GetIconFromFolder();
        }
```

Does anybody know of an obvious cause for this?

Comment: Is it erroring on just one file or is it a different file every time? If you run it on just that file does it still error?

Comment: You just reminded me that I forgot to add something to my question, it can be a different file each time it throws the exception and it can also fail on a file that previously succeeded

Comment: So then there is an actual significance to 3311 then? I was assuming there was not until you mentioned the error happens on different files.

Comment: The significance of the 3311 is that it seems to fail on the 3311th time regardless of if the file being processed has been successful before or not

Comment: So, just to be clear, if you were to reorder the files, it would *still* fail on #3311?

Comment: @Amy that is correct

Comment: Get one of the sysinternals tools that can track handles and watch the handle count of the process as its runs. You're almost certainly leaking handles *somewhere*. It might not be in the code shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are running out of `HANDLE`s. Windows has a finite number of handles and when you get one (in this case a handle to an icon), you are expected to release it after you no longer use it. If you don't, Windows will run out of free handles to throw around.

> If SHGetFileInfo returns an icon handle in the hIcon member of the SHFILEINFO structure pointed to by psfi, **you are responsible for freeing it with DestroyIcon when you no longer need it**.

So you will need to PInvoke [`DestroyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass your `shinfo.hIcon` to it at the end of your function.

The disposal of the Icon created with `FromHandle` will not destroy the original handle:

> When using this method, you must dispose of the original icon by using the DestroyIcon method in the Win32 API to ensure that the resources are released.

Comment: Is the destruction of the Icon not handled via the Using statement?

Comment: I'm looking at the source for `Icon`.  The `Dispose()` method destroys the handle.

Comment: @Amy: Sure, and regardless, the symptoms have "handle leak" written all over them. The OP should get a profiler or one of the sysinternals tools that can track handles owned by a process to see the handle count go up.

Comment: @Amy The `Dispose` method calls an internal method called `DestroyHandle` that only destroys the handle if it has ownership, which it does not take when you construct if from an existing handle as happened here.

Comment: Calling DestroyIcon seems to have solved the problem in my test harness. I have applied the same logic into the main application and will try there. Naturally if it works I will mark this as the answer.

I figured it would have been a leak somewhere but I just assumed the Dispose at the end of the Using would handle it for me

Comment: Have applied the logic in the main application and the number of successes has far exceeded the magic 3310 and still not crashed, so I'm assuming I'm on a home straight. Thanks very much!